# Can we solve this problem but with $N$ not normal: "If N is a normal subgroup of G with index m, show that $(\forall a \in G) a^m \in N$"?

Tags: group-theory

The proof I've seen uses the fact that $G/N$ has order $m$. So for any $aN \in G/N$, we have $(aN)^m = eN = a^mN$. So $a^m \in N$.

However, can't we just observe that the list of left cosets $N, aN, \ldots, a^{m-1}N, a^mN$ must have a repetition because the index of $N$ is $m$? Which means there is a $k$ such that $a^kN = N$ and the $k$ must factor $m$. So $a^m \in N$. But observing this does not require $N$ to be normal.

Comment: I expect you meant $a^m\in N$.  For a counterexample in the non-normal case, consider the group generated by a transposition inside $S_3$.

Comment: Why must $k$ factor $m$?

Comment: Ok, so $<(12)>$ is not normal because $(13)(12)(13) \notin <(12)>$. The index of $<(12)>$ is 3. But $(13)^3 \notin <(12)>$. And where the previous reasoning fails is in the assumption that $k$ must factor $m$. We have only two elements in the sequence $<(12)>, (13)<(12)>$ and 2 doesn't factor 3. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $k$ will factor $m$ when $N$ is normal because you can work in the group $G/N$.  Without $G/N$ being a group this argument won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why must $k$ divide $m$?

Take for example $S_3$ acting on $\{$1,2,3$\}$, and let $H$ be the $2$-element group that fixes 3. Then $H$ has index $3$ in $S_n$. However, let $\sigma$ be the permutation that transposes 2 and 3. Then $\sigma$ is not in $H$ and yet $\sigma^2=e$, so both $\sigma H \not = H$ and $\sigma^2H =H$. But $2$ does not divide $3$, so...